# How to trim video with start and end pos of seekbar using FFmpeg android?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing

String[] cmd = new String[]{"-ss", startTrim + ".00", "-t", endTrim + ".00", "-noaccurate_seek", "-i", videoPath, "-codec", "copy", "-avoid_negative_ts", "1", outputAudioMux};

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void trimVideo(ProgressDialog progressDialog) {

    outputAudioMux = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES).getAbsolutePath()
            + "/VidEffectsFilter" + "/" + new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss").format(new Date())
            + "filter_apply.mp4";

    if (startTrim.equals("")) {
        startTrim = "00:00:00";
    }

    if (endTrim.equals("")) {
        endTrim = timeTrim(player.getDuration());
    }

    String[] cmd = new String[]{"-ss", startTrim + ".00", "-t", endTrim + ".00", "-noaccurate_seek", "-i", videoPath, "-codec", "copy", "-avoid_negative_ts", "1", outputAudioMux};


    execFFmpegBinary1(cmd, progressDialog);
}





    private void execFFmpegBinary1(final String[] command, ProgressDialog prpg) {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog = prpg;

    try {
        ffmpeg.execute(command, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(String s) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(PlayerActivity.this, "Fail to generate video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d(TAG, "FAILED with output : " + s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "SUCCESS wgith output : " + s);


                String finalPath = outputAudioMux;
                videoPath = outputAudioMux;
                Toast.makeText(PlayerActivity.this, "Storage Path =" + finalPath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(PlayerActivity.this, ShareVideoActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("pathGPU", finalPath);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(PlayerActivity.this, new String[]{finalPath}, new String[]{"mp4"}, null);

            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Started gcommand : ffmpeg " + command);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait video triming...");
            }

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Startedf command : ffmpeg " + command);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Finished f command : ffmpeg " + command);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
        // do nothing for now
    }
}
```